# How do I approach an employer where I previously turned down a job offer?

Tags: job-change

When I was job hunting two years ago, I received two job offers. I now believe I chose the wrong one. I would like to reconnect with the employer I turned down, and ask if they would be interested in hiring me now. I'm agonizing about what to say to them.

I may be overthinking this, because I feel a little stupid and guilty. What is a good way to approach them?

Comment: If you did not burn the bridge back then, you should be fine. For this reason, whenever I decline an offer, I always send them a polite mail stating something like, "Thanks for your offer. Unfortunately, I cannot accept this offer since I have already accepted another offer. I look forward to an opportunity to work with you in the future."

Comment: I think they'll be happy that you remember them and still think well of them two years later.

Answer (score 10):

Treat it like a new application, you turned down a job offer 2 years ago, not last week. You can't expect that offer to still be open, and it might not even be the best idea to mention it.

So by all means check if they have jobs available, but don't bank on getting one, look elsewhere as well.

Comment: Yes I wouldn't even mention the bit about having previously applied there unless it is asked on the application itself. Even then I don't think they ask if you applied but only if you ever worked there or at another location.

Answer (score 2):

If you turned around with remorse a couple weeks later, that might look bad, but two years later?  They're not going to hold it against you or view you as frivolous or scattered for accepting a different offer and keeping it for two years.

If you made some contacts and think you might have made a good impression, reach out to them and say something along the lines of "I turned down an offer for that position a couple of years ago, but it was a tough decision and I was always impressed with your organization and appreciated the offer.  I've decided it's time to look for other opportunities and remember how much I liked you guys......"

If you don't think you made enough of an impression for them to remember you in a favorable light (would they have extended an offer if they didn't look at your favorably?), then start from scratch as just another applicant.

Saying no for perfectly sound reasons is not something anyone will take personally. No need to agonize over this.